# Involutory key for the substitution cipher

Tags: cryptography

I need to find all the involutory keys for the substitution cipher over $\mathbb{Z}_7$. I wasn't sure what can be the key for the substitution cipher.
For example, for the affine cipher, $e(x) = kx + a$, $(k,a)$ is the key.
However for the substitution cipher, I can't find the corresponding function.

Comment: I'd say the key is a permutation. So find all permutations of 7 elements that are involutions.